# How to create multiple user account types in drupal 7

Tags: 7, users

I want to customize the default registration process in drupal 7 like Paypal.

Users can choose their account types to register and  each account type has some corresponding fields to fill information.

For example in Paypal have 3 account types : Personal, Premier, Business

In drupal I only see 2 account types(anonymous and authentication), how can I add more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Anonymous user*, and *authenticated user* are two default roles used by Drupal (what other CMS's would call account types).

You can add custom roles from admin/people/permissions/roles.

[image: screenshot]

Once you created the new role, you can change the permissions given to that role using the "edit permissions" link that appears to the right side.

[image: screenshot]

If you then need to add new fields for user accounts having a specific role, you can use the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.
Drupal allows you to add new fields to the user accounts, from admin/config/people/accounts/fields, but the fields are visible for every user account, independently from the roles those accounts have.

[image: screenshot]

The Field Permissions module allows you to set who can enter a value for a field, who can edit a value for a field, and who can view the value of that field.
For example, if you want a "Editor ID" field that needs to be filled only from users with the editor role, you can add the permission of creating a value for that field, and editing it to users with the editor role; other users should be allowed to see that field, as well as the users with the editor role.