# Creating user profile types

Tags: views, users

I'm trying to make a record of different user profiles.
And each of them, possess or display different items, apart from those who normally come (Username, Email, Photo, etc..). Something like:

- Profile of Visitors         ==>>>> Only Images / Photo
- Employee Profile            ==>>>> Birth Date,  Curriculum Vitae, etc.
- Artist Profile,             ==>>>> Albums of: Videos, Music, and / or Photos
- Business Profile            ==>>>>Photo Albums / Images.

And each user is able to handle each of these elements.

E.g.:
- If I am a musician, update my music files or Albunes Photo.
- If employed Update My Currillo vitae. And so on ...

It will be possible to do this with Drupal 7?. Please Any suggestions?

Best Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create multiple user account types in drupal 7](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49571/how-to-create-multiple-user-account-types-in-drupal-7)

Comment: I don't think it's a dup. The other question mentions "account types", but really means roles. This question is actually about user bundles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Profile 2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) module

> Profile2 allows for creating multiple profile types, which may be
>   assigned to roles via permissions (e.g. a general profile + a customer
>   profile)

Also check [this wonderful answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/49574/4471) by [kiamlaluno](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/199/kiamlaluno)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to add all the fields to the user profile for all users, and then control access based on [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) and assigning roles.  If you only have a few fields with this requirement, controlling them via permissions may be the simplest way, but if you have to do a lot of fields this way, it will quickly become very complicated, and I would use Profile2  as Nikihil M suggested.